# Unable to Mock RegionManager.ActiveViews.First()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, prism

I am trying to write UT and stuck with below line.

> Product Code (Which is creating problem):

```
var view = RegionManager.Regions["Dummy"].ActiveViews.First() as IView;
```

> Unit Test (Relevant Code):

```
var regionManagerMock = new Mock<IRegionManager>();
var viewCollMock = new Mock<IViewsCollection>();
regionManagerMock.Setup(c => c.Regions["Dummy"].ActiveViews).Returns(viewCollMock.Object);
```

While executing this UT, I am getting below exception:

```
threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2147467261
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Source: "System.Core"
StackTrace: "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"
TargetSite: {TSource First[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource])}
```

However, I can see the value of this

```
RegionManager.Regions["Dummy"].ActiveViews
```

at runtime:

```
{Mock<Prism.Regions.IViewsCollection:670c>.Object}
Mock: {Mock<Prism.Regions.IViewsCollection:670c>}
Mock (Castle.Proxies.IViewsCollectionProxy): {Mock<Prism.Regions.IViewsCollection:670c>}
__interceptors: {Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[1]}
__target: null
Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
```

Comment: You need to create a mock of `IView` also. And add a setup for the `viewCollMock` as the following: viewCollMock.Setup(c => c.First()).Returns(iViewMock.Object)

Answer (score 2):

You have to flesh out the mock for `First` to be able to work with it.

Just

```
var viewCollMock = new Mock<IViewsCollection>();
```

will return `Null` all over the place, for example. The easiest thing is to create a conventional mock:

```
internal class MyMockViewsCollection : IViewsCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Inner { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    #region IViewsCollection
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add => Inner.CollectionChanged += value;
        remove => Inner.CollectionChanged -= value;
    }
    public bool Contains( object value ) => Inner.Contains( value );

    public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Inner.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)Inner).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion
}
```